# Active window title in Kubuntu panel?

Tags: kubuntu

I have Kubuntu 11.10 and have seen some people's desktops and they have the active window's title on their top panel like Unity and Macs do. I'm not looking for a global menu, they already have a widget for that preinstalled, I just want the title of the window (i.e. Google Chrome) to appear when it's open. I'm pretty sure it's a widget they have but I don't know what. Anyone know what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 0):

**Current Application Control ?**

The "Current Application Control" will show the active window's title on the plasmoid.

[image]